# Invertibility of adjacency matrix of nearest neighbor Ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

In Goldenfled's lectures on phase transitions and the renormalization group exercise 3.3 .
One is asked to consider nearest neighbor  Ising model (as the pic)

[image]

In the second problem, I let $B_i=S_i$ and

$$\beta \mathbf{J}_{i,j} = [A^{-1}]_{i,j}.$$

I found that the diffculty should be the fact that adjancency matrix $\mathbf{J}$ may not be invertible. But now i don't know how to deal with this properly. I saw some solutins people wrote adding diagonal terms to the matrix $\mathbf{J}$. Indeed this is just some shift of zero energy since $\sum_i S_i^2 =1$.
But how come $\mathbf{J}$ becomes invertible?　For example, if all spins are connected on graph, then $\mathbf{J}$ is not invertible, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can always pick diagonal terms large enough for $J$ to become (strictly) [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), hence invertible.

Comment: I see . Thanks very much !